# Multiple cascading paths Error - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to setup a new database using Entity Framework Core but I am getting an error when calling the command "Update-Database" saying:

```
"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Answers_Users_UserId' on table 'Answers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."
```

I do not plan on actually deleting anything from the database but I would be fine with setting it delete everything related to user if a user is deleted.

Here are my models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public int AnswersFlagged { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Dispute> Disputes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Dispute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string OptionOneText { get; set; }
    public string OptionTwoText { get; set; }
    public string OptionThreeText { get; set; }
    public string OptionOneImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string OptionTwoImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string OptionThreeImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DisputeId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool Flagged { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public Dispute Dispute { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Dispute> Disputes { get; set; }
}

public class DisputeCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DisputeId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Dispute Dispute { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the follow with no luck in my DbContext:

1)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
        .HasOne(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(b => b.Answers)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

2)

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
            .HasOne(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(b => b.Answers)
            .IsRequired(false);
 }
```

3)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this setup correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be solve in you `Answer` entity, change `DisputeId` as nullable:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DisputeId { get; set; }
    //..

    public Dispute Dispute { get; set; }
    //..
}
```

And configure your relationships this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
        .HasOne(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(b => b.Answers)
        .HasForeignKey(s =>s.UserId) ;

    modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Dispute)
        .WithMany(b => b.Answers)
        .HasForeignKey(s =>s.DisputeId) ;
}
```

The second relationship would be optional by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional), so that should solve your issue.

From [EF core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation:

> By convention, cascade delete will be set to Cascade for required
>   relationships and Restrict for optional relationships. Cascade means dependent entities are also deleted.
>   Restrict means that dependent entities that are not loaded into memory
>   will remain unchanged and must be manually deleted, or updated to
>   point to a valid principal entity. For entities that are loaded into
>   memory, EF will attempt to set the foreign key properties to null.
>
> If you have a foreign key property in your entity class then the
>   requiredness of the relationship is determined based on whether the
>   foreign key property is required or optional