# Data not seeding into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am following a tutorial on the documentation to try create my own database. The data was seeding properly with 3 tables and now I have added 6 I can't get the data to seed. I have tried creating a migration and updating the database. I did change some of the ON DELETE CASCADE to ON DELETE NO ACTION as I was getting an error with cascading and I am not sure if that is the reason that it isn't seeding.

For reference it was the tables 'Car' , 'PaymentPlan' & 'SalesMan' that was working previously

Initialise code:

```
using GarageSales.Data;
using GarageSales.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace GarageSales.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(GarageSalesContext context)
        {
            //context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Look for any Cars.
            if (context.Cars.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            var Customers = new Customer[]
            {
                new Customer{FirstName="Ray", LastName="Easton", Gender="Male", Address="2 Church Road", PostCode="BT35 0JW", RentalID=1, CarID=1, SalesManID=1},
                new Customer{FirstName="Amelie", LastName="Bush", Gender="Female", Address="54 Beach Gardens", PostCode="BT34 0JE", RentalID=2, CarID=2, SalesManID=2},
                new Customer{FirstName="Ray", LastName="Easton", Gender="Male", Address="2 Church Road", PostCode="BT67 0JW", RentalID=3, CarID=3, SalesManID=3}
            };
            foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
            {
                context.Customer.Add(customer);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var Cars = new Car[]
            {
                new Car{Model="I8",Manufacturer="BMW",EngineSize="1.5 L 3-cylinder"},
                new Car{Model="A5",Manufacturer="Audi",EngineSize="5.2 L V10"},
                new Car{Model="R8",Manufacturer="Audi",EngineSize="1.5 L 3-cylinder"}
            };
            foreach (Car car in Cars)
            {
                context.Cars.Add(car);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var SalesMen = new SalesMan[]
            {
                new SalesMan{FirstName="Darren",SurName="Dooning"},
                new SalesMan{FirstName="Jim",SurName="Campbell"},
                new SalesMan{FirstName="Jade",SurName="Mull"},
            };
            foreach (SalesMan SalesMan in SalesMen)
            {
                context.SalesMen.Add(SalesMan);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var Rentals = new Rental[]
            {
                new Rental{Price=150, Duration=36, Quote=3500, CustomerID=1, CarID=1, SalesManID=1},
                new Rental{Price=200, Duration=24, Quote=2000, CustomerID=2, CarID=2, SalesManID=2},
                new Rental{Price=400, Duration=12, Quote=4500, CustomerID=3, CarID=3, SalesManID=3}
            };
            foreach (Rental Rental in Rentals)
            {
                context.Rental.Add(Rental);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var PaymentPlans = new PaymentPlan[]
            {
                new PaymentPlan{CarID=1,SalesManID=1},
                new PaymentPlan{CarID=2,SalesManID=2},
                new PaymentPlan{CarID=3,SalesManID=3}
            };
            foreach (PaymentPlan PaymentPlan in PaymentPlans)
            {
                context.PaymentPlans.Add(PaymentPlan);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var Duration = new Duration[]
           {
                new Duration{DurationLength=36, RentalID=1, SalesManID=1},
                new Duration{DurationLength=24, RentalID=2, SalesManID=2},
                new Duration{DurationLength=12, RentalID=3, SalesManID=3}
           };
            foreach (Duration duration in Duration)
            {
                context.Duration.Add(duration);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Context class (The dataSets are 2 different ways as I figured late on and would have to go and change it to make the program run):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GarageSales.Models;

namespace GarageSales.Data
{
    public class GarageSalesContext: DbContext
    {
        public GarageSalesContext (DbContextOptions<GarageSalesContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentPlan> PaymentPlans { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SalesMan> SalesMen { get; set; }

        public DbSet<GarageSales.Models.Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GarageSales.Models.Duration> Duration { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GarageSales.Models.Rental> Rental { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Car");
            modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentPlan>().ToTable("PaymentPlan");
            modelBuilder.Entity<SalesMan>().ToTable("SalesMan");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Duration>().ToTable("Duration");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Rental>().ToTable("Rental");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need anymore information just ask

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: also you only need to call the SaveChanges once at the end. EF will track all intermediary changes in memory

Comment: @pjominet Oh that is good to know and also I do not get any error messages, the tables get created and I can see them but no data gets added to them. But if you are talking about the cascading error then it was something about my FK causing cycles or multiple cascade paths. I think it is because of the Customers table but have not been able to find a fix

Comment: ok try create your objects in order of the FKs they need. The ones without any FKs first and then the ones that depend on them. Or make sure that your FKs are nullable in your entities, then the order does not matter :)

Comment: @pjominet Would you be able to explain how to do that? I am new

Comment: for example in your customer class, the ``int CarID`` should be set to ``int? CarID``. a ``?`` behind types makes them nullable

Comment: @pjominet Oh, yes I just did it and it is still not displaying any data in the tables

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634320/multiple-cascading-paths-error-entity-framework-core or this https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/45128535/ef-core--configure-modelbuilder-to-fix-error--cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-

Comment: @pjominet Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202947/discussion-between-darren-d19-and-pjominet).

Comment: @pjominet tried to follow the answer in that link and still no luck, no data is being inserted